# C++ class scope suggestions popup window, can I filter out properties declared on parent classes?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, intellisense, unreal-engine5

I'm creating Blueprint exposed function libraries in Unreal Engine. It requires me to declare my functions in a class that inherits what looks like 100s of attributes.

Therefore when I start typing the scope name of my class and a scoping operator `myClass::` I get suggestions of attributes that comes from the parent class - none of which I really want to see.

Can I filter or order the suggestions so that its easier to find attributes that I've declared myself directly in the child class?

[image] https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAgo1.png

^ Desirably, in the popup menuI would see foobar at the top - or only foobar. Also interested in other advice around how I can search in my code easily. Currently when I dont remember the name of a function - but know what library I created the function I usually end up looking in the header file. Would be nice if I could somehow just get an overview of the functions or attributes declared on the class without having to switch files.